# Django- How to add user data in different models?

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in Django and I'm trying to make an app that stores attendance status of a user in various courses. I have an idea about how to make a Userprofile model and add one or two extra fields when user registers.
I want to make a separate model for attendance that contains several columns (course code, name, attended, absent) and I want to create different tables for each user. I tried using

```
user=models.OneToOneField(User)
```

This doesn't work. When I try to see that model on admin page, The error that I get is:

> No column such as attendance.user_id

I am using Django 1.8. and python 2.7

Comment: Sounds like maybe you forgot to do the migration?

Comment: Okay, I tried to make migration again and I'm getting this prompt : you're trying to add a non nullable field user to attendance without a default.
Now what do I select for that? I can't provide a default user obviously, so what might be the correct way to do what I'm trying to do?

What i mean is, why can't this be just like UserProfile class, which doesn't raise any such issues?

Comment: "I want to create different tables for each user"

Is that what you meant to say? You surely don't intend to have a table for each user, right?

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I want. The attendance record has fields like -(course code, name, attended, absent). Each user has around 6 courses. I want to be able to store attendance record for all these courses and map them to a user.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong relationship between your models.  You don't need a separate 'table' per user, you need an attendance record for each user.  Something like the below should get you on the right track.

```
from django.db import models

class Userprofile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Attendance(models.Model):
    user = models.Foreignkey(Userprofile)
    attend = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: But that wouldn't satisfy the requirement. 
The attendance table contains columns - (course code, name, attended, absent).   
Each user has attendance record for 5 courses. How do I save all of them and map them to a particular user?